# Active or Passive sentences

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

Grammarly flags passive sentences for consideration to be changed to active as default. Why is this? Is there a rule advising active rather than passive when writing? Does it apply to certain types of writing (academic, formal, etc.)

Comment: Yes, some people have a "rule" or guideline or style that prefers active voice to passive voice. Active is only more correct than passive in the presence of such artificial parameters. In the basic language, even in formal settings, passive is not inherently inferior.

Comment: The much-touted rule that prefers active voice over passive is but a relic from _Strunk and White_ and need not be taken seriously anymore.

Comment: It would help if you gave examples of sentences in the passive that seem acceptable to you but that grammarly  calls improper or awkward (whatever the term). For instance, there seems to be no problem from Grammarly here: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/passive-voice/

Comment: In any case, grammarly is not a correct source for grammatical advice, any more than facebook is for political advice. We're not responsible for what they say, much of which is nonsense.